# Record cursor movement

Tags: cursor, desktop-recording

This is more of a conceptual/implementation question, rather than a specific language problem.

Does anybody have any insight into cursor movement recording?
It's very easy to get a cursor's current position, but how would you go about recording the path followed by the cursor?
(To the degree of detail where it could be plotted graphically without ambiguity as to the path taken)

I imagine you could record the cursor's current position repeatedly after a small duration, logging it all to make a list of chronologically visited coordinates,
but I'm not sure how frequent (or feasible) the recording should take place; every 10 ms?
I've not even encountered a method of sleeping for such short durations to the nescessary precision!

I'm concerned also about the performance of the sleeping and recording during intense CPU usage; when the user is using the mouse to interact with intensive software.

I'm not even entirely sure where the cursor is really moving.
If I sweep my cursor across the screen, has the computer (somewhere internally) acknowledged that I crossed all those pixels,
or has my mouse really told it "I was there, now I'm over here, now I'm there".

I do also seek a method of differentiating between fast and slow movement, but for now, I can just observe the plot spacing on a graph of the visited coordinates.

Does anybody have any insight into this? 
Any potential pitfalls; are my concerns legitimate?
Am I going the wrong way about this?

(As is observable, I really need some guidance in the matter)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this cursor tracking intended to be within your own application, or across the whole system? Also, which kind of system?

Comment: My own application, but not the one logging the data. Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

It's far easier to log the mouse movements within the same application - just log something on every `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message. You will get a message periodically updating the mouse pointer location. You will not get a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message for every pixel the mouse crosses, but it will jump depending on how fast you move the mouse and how busy the system is.

Logging mouse movements in some other application is going to be slightly more involved. If you have written both the logger and the application being logged, then you can handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in the application being logged, and send a corresponding message to your logger application. Your choice of IPC; a simple `SendMessage()` might be sufficient.

Logging mouse movements across the *whole system* is a totally different problem. You may have to hook in at somewhere closer to the driver level.

I just thought of another approach - the [CBT (Computer-Based Training) hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are designed to provide exactly this sort of information across applications. I've never used these though, so you'll have to do more investigation.

Comment: Is the WM_MOUSEMOVE message issued at the same frequency as the computer acknowledges hardware movement? (I assume it's at an acceptable frequency anyway)

Comment: No, not in Windows. What happens is the hardware drivers sends a "hey the mouse moved" signal to the OS, and the OS internally sets a flag on the window that the mouse is currently over, saying "this window needs a mouse move update". Later, when the window's message queue is empty, Windows looks at the "needs a mouse move update" flag, and if it is set, generates a single WM_MOUSEMOVE message with the latest location and then clears the flag. So if for some reason you believe you need to get more frequent updates than that, then you'll definitely be looking at a driver implementation.